# Tiny ImageNet in original size

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, dataset, imagenet

For a project, I need to have Tiny ImageNet images with their original size as ImageNet, i.e. 256*256 pixels.

Is there any version of Tiny ImageNet as such? On the other side, is there any index map to know which images from the original dataset have been selected to construct the Tiny version?

**Update:** Is there any matching table to specify which image id in the Tiny is corresponding to that in the original ImageNet?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can upscale the image size to 256*256, and this is a common approach to fit the image shape to the model required input shape.

Secondly, this is the dataset you need (https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/tiny-imagenet/data), in `wnids.txt - list of the used ids from the original full set of ImageNet`. You can download the original ImageNet data and use this file to map.